# All visited urls ending with _900 in cache_page tables

Tags: 7, caching

I came across strange problem with drupal 7 and caching for anonymous users. After clearing cache, newly visited pages by anonymous users are stored in cache_page with _900 at the end of url like this www.example.com/examplepage_900. Anybody know what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Is it a port number?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have no idea why are such links created in cache tables. All visited pages ends with _900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by module http://drupal.org/project/resp_img after installing the latest version, everything is ok.